# I have an issue in node js npm package node-adodb - (node:13328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Spawn C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe error

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a code to read an access file using node-adodb package but I have an error like this.  below is my code. I try to using some simple select query for reading data from access file.

```
(node:13328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Spawn C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe error
    at ChildProcess.child.on.exitCode (C:\projects\partdcScaffold\node_modules\node-adodb\lib\spawn.js:120:37)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)




async function f() {

  let file = await fs.appendFile(inputFileName, data, async function (err) {
    if (err)
    {
      console.log(err);
    }else {
      console.log('Saved!');
      let extracted = await unrar(inputFileName, './output');
      console.log("created!");
      await updateInvesmentsInfo();
    }
  });
}

f();

async function updateInvesmentsInfo() {
  fs.copyFile('./output/mutualfunds.accdb', './output/node-adodb.mdb', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('mutualfunds.accdb was copied to node-adodb.mdb');
  });
  const connection = ADODB.open('Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=./output/Database.accdb;');
  await initializer.initMongo();
  let data = await connection.query('select some table');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
}
```